# user-error: Not in table data field

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The following table

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 3 :tcolumns 4 :scope file :block 2015-6 :narrow 60
| Headline     | Time   |      |      |
|--------------+--------+------+------|
| *Total time* | *3:57* |      |      |
|--------------+--------+------+------|
| Tasks        | 3:57   |      |      |
| 1            |        | 3:57 |      |
| 2            |        |      | 3:57 |
#+TBLFM: @3$5..@>$5=vsum($2..$4)*100
```

gives me

```
user-error: Not in table data field
```

where it should add the total of all previous columns to into a new column and multiply them by 100. Via http://notes.secretsauce.net/notes/2014/10/01_org-mode-for-invoices.html

I see two solutions a) add a command to `TBLFM` to add an additional
column b) make clocktable generate the additional column, but I don't
know how to do either.

Comment: You only have four columns in the table, but you are putting the result in column 5.  If you add a new column it should work.

Comment: I can't add a new column, the table is a clocktable, so it's generated.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick hack that you could bind to a key that adds the extra column if needed and then recalculates:

```
(defun maybe-add-column-and-update ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (end-of-line)
    (if (= (org-table-current-column) 5)
        (let ((org-table-fix-formulas-confirm
               (lambda (arg) nil)))
          (org-table-insert-column)))
    (org-table-recalculate 'iterate)))
```

Comment: Can't do that - the `TBLFM` is executed directly after the clocktable is generated.

Comment: @Reactormonk, How are you adding the clocktable to your file?